# Doing an AJAX POST followed by GET with Flask

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

My goal here is to have the user fill out a form, send that information in a POST request to the flask server, then render a template using that form information (after it undergoes some logic on the server).

So far, I have completed the POST part of all of this. I am trying to render a template right now inside the `if request.method == POST'`, and I guess that's not working right now.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
@app.route('/filteredsearch/', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def filteredsearch():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.data)
        tables = data['checkboxes']
        filter_results = getFilteredEntities(tables = tables)
        print filter_results                          #This works
        return render_template("filteredsearch.html", entities = filter_results)
```

Do I have to do a separate `GET` request on the success of my `POST` function? If so, how would I do that?

Here is the AJAX request (if it matters, this code can be called on every single page of the app):

```
$.ajax({
              url:"/filteredsearch/",
              type: 'POST',
              data: json,
              contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
              success: function() {
                           alert("Done");
                       }
          });
```

So, ideally I can render a template while I'm posting. If that's not the case, how do I go about doing a `GET` request from the same ajax function?

I know that typically you use `url_for()` for a `GET` request, is that an option given that I'm in JS at this point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you use an ajax request to return data that you then dynamically display in the page.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/filteredsearch/",
        type: 'POST',
        data: json,
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(evt) {
            $("#results").html = evt.data;
        }
});
```

If you are going to redirect to another template then why not just click submit on a form that makes a POST and then responds with the new template. If you **actually** want to redirect to a whole new page after the ajax request has come back (which is going to be slower than just displaying the information you've already received) then you could change the window.location. Something like `window.location = 'http://www.example.com'` would take the user to example.com.

Comment: Is this a flask thing that I've missed? I need to populate the new template with a variable (called `filter_results` above). Is that a possibility with the method you're describing?

Comment: Not really. This is a web development thing. If you just want to make a post request and then respond with a rendered template don't make it as an AJAX request. Just use a html form with a submit button. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: But I need to do server-side work. Wouldn't that mean I need to use AJAX

Comment: No you just make an html form and let the user click the submit button. `<form action="/filteredsearch/" method="POST"><input type="text" name="search><input type="submit"></form>` A click on that submit button will make a post request to /filteredsearch which you can then process serverside and respond with your rendered template.

Comment: Won't I still be doing a POST though? I mean, the problem at the moment is that I can't render an HTML template while doing a POST

Comment: @AlexChumbley - you will be doing a POST and then responding to the POST request with a 200 OK response (with a HTML body).  Alternately, you could redirect after the POST to a different page using `flask.redirect`.  That would result in a GET request to the page you redirect to.

Comment: A POST request really isn't that different from a GET. It just has a bit of data encoded in the headers. The problem is that you are sending a response but aren't doing anything with it when you receive it in the browser. When you submit a form the browser will automatically handle the response. Things will just work.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, but how is that different that returning a rendered template from a POST request?

Comment: It's not. The server side (Flask) code would not change. At the moment you are making an AJAX POST request and then doing NOTHING with the response. That response will include the rendered template. See how you have a `success` parameter to your AJAX request? That function gets called with the response. From what you are telling me there is NO reason for you to be making this POST request as an AJAX call. Just doing it the normal way (i.e by clicking on a submit button in a form) will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a little late, but i just had the same problem than you.

I needed to make a POST with Ajax and then if it succeeded I needed to make a GET request to flask to return a rendered template. Something like:

FLASK PART:

```
@app.route('/something', methods=['POST'])
def something_post():
    # Get JSON object passed with Ajax request
    elems = request.json
    # Do stuff
    # If everithing is OK, return success message
    return json.dumps({'success': True}), 200, {'ContentType': 'application/json'}

@app.route('/something', methods=['GET'])
def something_get():
    # Return template
    return render_template('something.html')
```

AJAX PART:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: myJsonString, // JASON object passed to flask
        url: '/something',
        contentType: "application/json",
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            # If we succed we make a request to get the template
            window.location.href = "/something";
            # With this line we are making a simple GET request to Flask and the template returned is opened in the current window
        }
});
```

Please, note than I'm far, far away to be an Ajax expert. I don't know if this is the correct way to do it but it was the simplest way I found.

Comment: Works perfect. Ty

Comment: How can we transfer data along with the request?