# How to use Flask's render_template from an ajax POST form submit

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

I am hoping to get an answer to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790980/ajax-post-returning-render-template-in-flask):

I have a jQuery form that sends JSON data to a certain URL that is served by Flask:

```
    <div id="form">      
      <form id="send">        
        <input type="submit" value="Continue" >
      </form>
    </div>



jQuery(document).on('ready', function() {
        jQuery('form#send').bind('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var form = this;
        json = geojson.write(vectors.features);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/create",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(){},
            data: json

        });
    });
});
```

On the Flask side, I have a simple function that renders an HTML page displaying the JSON object:

```
@app.route('/create', methods=['POST'])
def create():
    content = request.json
    print content
    return render_template('string.html', string = content)
```

I know the JSON is being passed, because I can see it printed in the console running the Flask server:

[image: console print]

**The problem is that the template is rendered as part of the response of the Ajax request, but I want the template to be rendered as a new html page:**

[image: response of request]

Comment: where did u declare the var $SCRIPT_ROOT or is it a PHP var?

Comment: It's irrelevant to this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out I actually didn't need to use jQuery for this, instead I can submit JSON simply using an html form with a hidden field (as hinted at in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204297/doing-an-ajax-post-followed-by-get-with-flask?rq=1) question):

```
<div id="form">

      <form id="send" method="post" action="create" onsubmit="getJSON()" enctype='application/json'>        
        <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
        <input type="hidden" name="jsonval" value=""/>
      </form>
</div>
```

And then use javascript to populate the form when the button is clicked:

```
function getJSON(){

            json = geojson.write(vectors.features);
            var formInfo = document.forms['send'];
            formInfo.jsonval.value = json;

        }
```

Answer (score 8):

try this,

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/create",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(){},
        data: json
        success:function(response){
            document.write(response); 
       }

    });
```

Comment: I want to render the template at a new URL, not on the same page.

Comment: No example I have seen has included this simple last success line yet they all claim to succeed with successful rendering of the next interactive page. They don't work!!! Your does. This was a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer by @camdenl does solve the problem, which means that you must use a form to post and ajax doesn't work for redirect.

Use form, and set `<input type="hidden" name="jsonval" value=""/>` so that it won't appear on your page. And then you could set `formInfo.jsonval.value` to what you want in javascript.

For example

```
formInfo.jsonval.value = JSON.stringify(box_value);
```

and in app.py

```
@app.route('/generate', methods=['GET','POST'])
def generate():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = json.dumps(request.form)
        data = json.loads(result)['jsonval']
```