# Issue making an AJAX call to flask render_template

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, flask

Suppose that I have two radio buttons (labeled 1 and 2) and some text at the bottom of the page. By default the value is `-1` for the text and no check boxes are selected. If I click one of the radio buttons I want to change the value of the text to be either 1 or 2 depending on the radio input that was selected. To do so I have based the code on the [AJAX call described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24891804/667648). Here is the code:

`hello.py`

```
from flask import (
    Flask, render_template, request
)

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def hello():
    level = -1
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        level = int(request.form.get('level', False))
    return render_template('test.html', value=level)
```

`templates/test.html`

```
<html>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input name="level" type="radio" id="1">1</input>
      <input name="level" type="radio" id="2">2</input>
    </form>
    {{ value }}
  </body>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
        console.log( $( this ).attr("id"));
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: { level: $( this ).attr("id") },
          success: function(response) {
            console.log("HERE");
            document.write(response);
          },
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

When I call `flask run`, selecting either radio button will change the value to either `1` or `2` but I cannot select either radio button a second time. The page will hang on the second selection, and I am not sure what is going on.

Note: Although this may seem like overkill, I have a more complex form submission in the larger project I am working on, this is simply a MVCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is dynamic content creation, you need to anchor the `change` event handler to an outer tag:

```
<html>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"> </script>
  <body>
   <div class='wrapper'>
   <form>
     <input name="level" type="radio" id="1">1</input>
     <input name="level" type="radio" id="2">2</input>
   </form>
    <p>{{ value }}</p>
  </div>
 </body>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wrapper').on('change', 'input[type=radio]', function(){
       console.log( $( this ).attr("id"));
       $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: { level: $( this ).attr("id") },
       success: function(response) {
        console.log("HERE");
        $('p').text(response.toString());
      },
    });
    });
  });
  </script>
</html>
```